# calculating camera angle from floor

Tags: android, opencv, math, android-sensors

Im trying to compute the camera angle from floor. I have placed the device on floor to calculate the angle.  Im using the following code to do calculate angle.

```
 @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == 1) {
            float[] values = event.values;

            float f3 = this.pastX * 0.925F + values[0] * 0.07499999F;
            float f2 = this.pastY * 0.925F + values[1] * 0.07499999F;
            float f1 = this.pastZ * 0.925F + values[2] * 0.07499999F;
            this.pastX = f3;
            this.pastY = f2;
            this.pastZ = f1;
            applyRotationMatrix(this.rotationMatrix, f3, f2, f1, this.gravitySensorCorrected);
            double d = computeAngleOfPhoneFromFloorInDegrees(this.gravitySensorCorrected);
        }
    }
```

Following is the code that I use to apply rotation matrix,

```
private static void applyRotationMatrix(float[] rotationMatrix, float f3, float f2, float f1, float[] correctedOp) {
        correctedOp[0] = (rotationMatrix[0] * f3 + rotationMatrix[1] * f2 + rotationMatrix[2] * f1);
        correctedOp[1] = (rotationMatrix[3] * f3 + rotationMatrix[4] * f2 + rotationMatrix[5] * f1);
        correctedOp[2] = (rotationMatrix[6] * f3 + rotationMatrix[7] * f2 + rotationMatrix[8] * f1);
    }
```

Then I use the following code to calculate the angle in degrees

```
    private static double computeAngleOfPhoneFromFloorInDegrees(float[] floatArray) {
        float f3 = floatArray[0];
        float f1 = floatArray[1];
        float f2 = floatArray[2];
        double d1 = Math.sqrt(f3 * f3 + f1 * f1 + f2 * f2);
        double d2 = f1 / d1;
        d1 = f2 / d1;
        d1 = Math.acos(d1 / Math.sqrt(d2 * d2 + d1 * d1));
        if (d2 > 0.0D) {
            return 180.0D * d1 / 3.141592653589793D;
        }
    }
```

But then this code doesn't always works and sometimes provides wrong angle. How do I calculate the camera angle from floor? It prints `NaN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You don't return if `d2 < 0.0D`
- I think the code should just be `asin(f1 / d1)`, and you are over-complicating the calculation.

Comment: May I know why asin ?

Comment: Somehow I have been trying to calculate the angle after placing mobile on ground

Comment: Because `f1` (the Z-component) is opposite the angle you want to calculate, not adjacent to. And sine is opposite / hypotenuse.